# pointers and its operators

Tags: c

I know I asked these question before but I did not get the right answer they said me to go through google but I found nowhere and I really wanna know I cant leave it on.The concept of pointers

How the GREAT Dennis Ritchie wrote the code for `&` and `*` operators? How do they work?

Because I want to know the code I want make my own pointers, not just saying `int *p;` I want to know the working how it is going retrieve the data from an address.

Can we write the code in C? Is that possible without declaring a variable as a pointer?
With a normal variable `int p;`, can we store the address of other variable and retrieve its data?

Please don't say to use:

```
int main()
{
    int p,a;
    p=(void *)&a;  // dont say these syntax to store the adress
    *(void *)p=45; // and these syntax to restore the data
}
```

I know that code, but is there any other way to make it through? I have been thinking about it from months. Actually I work on micro controllers, they even use the `#` symbol as a pointer how does that work? There must be some code behind it.

Comment: FWIW, the original C compiler was written in PDP assembly.

Comment: First make sure your spelling&grammar is correct, your post is properly formatted and your question is understandable, we'll be a lot more likely to be able to help you then...

Comment: You need to learn assembly. And you can't do what you want in that code segment.

Comment: ok thank you guys but sorry i just chat on mobile with my friends so i was habituated thats why i cannot concentrate on the grammer and spelling really sorry guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below `*p` is an operation called *load indirect*, and below `*p=v` is an operation called *store indirect*. `&a` is just syntax for the location of `a`. both of those operations are built in to the machine code of all modern computers.

Comment: It is different for every kind of machine, and it is not C code, because the machine does not use C code internally. At a certain point, you can't write things in C any more, because you have to explain what it means at the assembly level. There is not a direct mapping from C to assembly, for any machine. That is why you have a C compiler.